# Delete all shared preferences of my Application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a nice way to delete all SharedPreferences (= all data from all key to value maps, not just all values from a single map) of my application programmatically on Android? There were similar questions here, but I really want to delete **all**, not just "OneOfMany", so

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("OneOfMany", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

is not good solution.

And **programmatically** means that Application manager/My app/Clear data is also not good solution. Any idea?

Comment: My question is no duplicate of "Deleting shared preferences", or at least trere is no reply to it. There (and also here now) are just replys how to delete (one or more) values from a single SharedPreferences key to value map.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
```

Comment: The same as previous reply. You are clearing just one of key->value map. Not all maps.